# XOR of users password Scrypt key and Random 32 bit salt?

Tags: encryption

I am trying to encrypt users private keys with the user password but if a user provides a weak password then the scrypt key generated from it will also be weak and suspectible to attack.

Let say the user generates a 32 bit key and the algorithm generates another 32 bit random salt. Then the key generated by XOR'ing these two keys will be used to enrypt the private keys.
My question is: Is it safe to do so, will it be secure enough?

Comment: Where are you storing the salt? Or is the idea that you *don't* store it, but have to guess it by brute force when decrypting? (If so, I'd recommend just increasing the scrypt cost factor instead.) And are you XORing the salt with the password before feeding it to scrypt, or with the scrypt output aftwerwards? Oh, and by "32 bit key", do you mean a key with (approximately) 32 bits of entropy, or a key that's actually 32 bits long?

Comment: I am xoring the salt with the password before feeding it to scrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

Scrypt is a psuedorandom function, the output will always be strong unless you purposely choose bad parameters. I would suggest just concatenating the password and the salt then feeding it into scrypt. That way the salt isn't limited in strength by the size of the password.

Comment: Scrypt already has a dedicated "salt" input, so it would make more sense to use that.

Comment: Can i put salt to public knowledge ?, keeping the user passwords sae with users?

Comment: A salt implies that you keep it in your database next to the account so yes. But as for storing password equivalent data, in this case no.